# How do I reset to factory settings on my Lumia 950?

Tags: backup, lumia-950

I was stuck at 21% in my restore with a new Lumia 950. I kept getting this message box with two buttons "Don't Restore" and "Try Again". The message ends with: 
"...If you tap Don't restore, you won't be given an option to restore your backup later."

I turned it off to try again, but that didn't help. How can I start over?

Comment: you can simply head to settings> system > about> scroll down a bit and tap reset this phone.,

This will factory reset/hard reset the device. You will lose all files and apps on the device.

Comment: @KolappanNathan You are correct; these are the same steps. I made the assumption that the Lumia 950 would be different. This didn't show up in my search for the 950.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same way as factory reset with buttons combination for W8/8.1 or with Windows Recovery Tool (PC program)

Comment: The complete answer: https://www.onmsft.com/news/how-to-hard-factory-reset-your-lumia-950-or-lumia-950-xl.
While your phone is completely shut off, hold down both the power button and the volume down button. (if your phone turns on, you need to repeat this process). This combo should be held for approximately 10 to 15 seconds until a vibration is felt.
After the vibration is felt, release the power button and keep holding the volume down button. You should now see an exclamation mark on your screen.
Now press the following key combinations: Volume up, Volume Down, Power Button, Volume Down.